# Understanding "def main" and "overloading" in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming, overloading

I often see some code with

```
def main(A,B)
    some steps
```

described as an "overloading for the main function", after reading something more specific about Python I know that this is not true because:

- Python is a *loseless type* language
- a function/method in Python doesn't even know the type for a given parameter, nor python cares

I'm also not sure if there is a real distinction between instances and "static methods" or "class methods", probably they are the same thing and the only difference is given by the use of decoratos, but this is probably related to my first approach to a functional language after spending so much time with C/C++ .

Even more, in Python, the first indentation level is used as an entry point ( like main() in C/C++ ), so I don't get why you should define a main at an indentation level that is different from the really first one.

The general idea that I have about Python's keywords is that the keywords have a special semantic value rather than a real defined syntax ( probably it's because the C++ is less "idiomatic" , I don't really know how explain that ), they are used as a placeholder for something and they give a special meaning to the section where they are applied. There also special variables like `__name__` that are there just to store special informations and nothing more.

After all this small bits of information stored in my brain I still dont' get the real meaning of the first code example:

- what is special about the main() function ?
- what is the point of defining something like a "main" function if it's not real "main"
- how Python decide what function is the one to call if it's not typed ?
- there is a difference between how the interpreter reads `__init__.py` files and other files ?

Comment: You have several different questions here, better to separate them into separate questions.  Also, where have you seen this referred to as "overloading the main function"?

Comment: @BrenBarn I found it very often in various resources about scripting and creating small programs in Application that offer Python APIs. If you want a specific example I need to dig it because I tend to trash this stuff, but it's really common to see that.

Comment: @BrenBarn also how i can shift this question into 4 if there are basically the same thing from different angles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

#### `main()` function

Nothing is special about it.  You have to call it yourself, by doing something like:

```
def main():
    print "This is main"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### Why use `main()`

The reason you might do that is to keep your main entry-point code together in a convenient way.  For instance, if you create some variables in `main()`, they won't be global variables, which avoids polluting the global namespace.  It also prevents the `main()` function from being run if you import the module from another (instead of running it directly as a script).  This can be useful if you don't want to do some initialization (e.g., print messages) when importing, but you do want to do them when running as a standalone script.

#### How does Python decide which function to call

Python does not support "overloading" in this sense.  There can only be one function with a given name in a given namespace.  If you make a second function with the same name (or second method with the same name in the same class), you overwrite the first one completely.

#### `__init__.py`

This question is not really related to your others.  But no, it doesn't process them in a different way.  It processes them at a different time (when you import a package, rather than a module in a package), but the code in them is run just the same as the code in any other Python file.

Comment: so the main really is a function like any other ?

Comment: @pictr: Yes, just like any other.

Answer (score 1):

main() in python is just a function name. The common idiom

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #do something
```

is a shortcut to figure out of the code in this file is being run as a program rather than imported as a module.

Because python is intended to by type-free, the community puts a strong emphasis on conventions and best practices. This doesn't provide the same level of predictability as a compiler, but it helps keep the chaos at bay. Readability is a core python value and idioms like this provide valuable structure.

Python does not support function overloading in the sense that other languages do. In strongly typed languages you might write multiple versions of the same function with the same name but varying input arguments:

```
void DoSomething (int a) {};
void DoSomething (float f) {};
void DoSomething (string s){};
```

In python there is no equivalent idiom. In most cases it's unneeded: for a numeric operation you don't really care if the incoming numbers are floats, ints or whatever -- only that they support the correct operators.  This is where the python mantra of 'duck typing' comes in - if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it's a duck.  So python functions idiomatically [look for functions or operators on incoming arguments rather than checking their types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435122/does-this-approach-to-python-duck-typing-mixed-with-isinstance-make-sense?rq=1).

As for instance vs static methods: 
In python every instance method implicitly gets the owning instance as the first argument to a function:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.variable = arg
    def example(self):
        print self.variable

fred = Test(999)  # note: no 'self' passed here
fred.example()
>>> 999
joe = Test(-1)
joe.example()
>>> -1
```

a class method gets the class type, rather than an instance, as the implicit first argument.  Class methods can see class-level variables, which are defined in the class scope rather than in the instance scope - but they don't know anything about a particular instance.

```
class TestCls (Test)
   CLASS_VARIABLE = "hello"
   # other behavior inherited from Test

   @classmethod
   def class_example(cls):
       print cls.CLASS_VARIABLE


barney = TestCls(123)
barney.example()
>>> 123
barney.class_example() # again, no explicit class passed in
>>> 'hello'
```

a static method gets no implicit arguments at all:

```
class TestStatic (TestCls):
    CLASS_VARIABLE = 'goodbye'
    # inherited stuff again
    @staticmethod
    def static_test():
        print "behold, I have no implicit argument"
```

Static and class methods also don't need an instance to be called:

```
wilma = TestStatic(123)
wilma.static_test()  # you can call from an instance
>>> behold, I have no implicit argument
# or not:
TestStatic.static_test()
>>> behold, I have no implicit argument 
TestStatic.class_example()
>>> goodbye # the method is inherited, but the class variable come from this class
```